# What "good" (illuminating) examples are there of elements in $\omega^\omega\setminus\omega^{<\omega}$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In the Von Neumann definition of ordinals every ordinal is the well-ordered set of smaller ordinals.

Let $X$ be the set of all ordinals expressible in Cantor normal form with an arbitrarily long (eventually zero) sequence of integers $S_n$ (i.e. $n\in\Bbb N_{\geq0}$) by the expression:

$\sum_n\omega^ns_n$

For example $\omega^35+\omega^2+6\in X$

I would naturally think of the set $X$ as the supremum of the above, which I think of as the ordinal $\omega^\omega$ because every ordinal below that is of the given form.

However I've seen the statement: $X=\omega^{<\omega}$ or $X=\Bbb N^{<\omega}$ which leads me to think of the above as wrong.

Presumably then, $X$ is not an ordinal and the difference between $\omega^{<\omega}$ and $\omega^{\omega}$ is akin to the difference between a sum and a product, where the former requires finitely many nonzero terms?

What "good" (illuminating) examples are there of elements in $\omega^\omega\setminus\omega^{<\omega}$ or $\omega^\omega\setminus X$?  I need to see some to better grasp the dichotomy.

Comment: What is $\omega^{<\omega}$ for ordinal exponentiation?

Comment: A set $Y$ is transitive iff $\forall y\in Y\,(y\subset Y)$. A set is an ordinal iff it is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$. Any set of ordinals is well-ordered by $\in. $ We conclude that an ordinal is the same thing as a transitive set of ordinals. The set $X$ as defined in your 2nd sentence IS transitive and therefore $X$ is an ordinal.

Comment: Thank-you @DanielWainfleet I guess this the Von Neumann construction of the integers guarantees this. You would think this would help to settle some matter but alas now I have further questions about the relation of ordinals to transitive sets with a periodic orbit upon truncation! The example I give has a fixed point, of course.

Comment: Actually @DanielWainfleet I think I've worked it out, it won't be well ordered if it has a periodic orbit. It'll be effectively the product of an ordinal and a cyclic group.

Comment: What are you referring to ? $X$ is an ordinal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use $\omega^{<\omega}$ to denote the finite sequences, or the eventually $0$ sequences, of natural numbers.

But the notation doesn't make a lot of sense as ordinal arithmetic. The reason is that ordinal arithmetic is continuous, so $\omega^\omega=\sup\{\omega^n\mid n<\omega\}$, which is what you'd normally expect from $\omega^{<\omega}$ as far as notation goes.

We *do* use $\omega^{<\omega}$ when we think about $\omega^\omega$ as the space of *all* sequences. This is akin to cardinal exponentiation, not ordinal exponentiation. And in that sense, an element of $\omega^\omega\setminus\omega^{<\omega}$ would be the sequence $\langle 1,2,3,4,\dots\rangle$. But again, this is not ordinal exponentiation.

Comment: ok, it seems you mean e.g. $S_n=1,2,3,4\ldots$ and $X\ni x=\sum_n \omega^{n-1} n$ in which case yes, that seems to make sense now.  $X$ isn't in fact, an ordinal, is it?  But $\omega^\omega$ is the smallest ordinal that contains every element of $X$. Is that right?

Comment: Look, the summation is given by the limit of its initial segments (in this case, finite initial segments). So if the sequence is not eventually $0$, you get to the ordinal $\omega^\omega$. Therefore your $X$, as an ordinal, is literally $\omega^\omega+1$. Good analogy to this is taking the (ordinal) sum of $\sum 2^n\cdot s_n$ where $s\colon\omega\to\omega$. Unless $s$ is eventually $0$, this is going to be $\omega$ itself.

Comment: I imagine that there is, but I don't know what you mean exactly, so I find it hard answering your question.

Comment: Well, arbitrarily long finite sequences or "eventually $0$" sequences both mean the same thing in this context, which is what I suspect you also meant.

Comment: ok, I'm getting it now. It'd be a great help if you confirmed whether or not $X$ as defined above is an ordinal or not.  Arthur (possibly unintentionally or by assumption) says it is in his answer but I'm struggling to reconcile that with the notion that as sets $X\subsetneq\omega^\omega$

Comment: If $X$ is all the possible finite sums of ordinals below $\omega^\omega$, then $X=\omega^\omega$.

Comment: Is that the same as: Let $X$ be the set of all ordinals expressible in Cantor normal form with an arbitrarily long (eventually zero) sequence of integers $S_n$ (i.e. $n\in\Bbb N_{\geq0}$) by the expression:

$\sum_n\omega^ns_n$

For example $\omega^35+\omega^2+6\in X$?

Comment: Yes, that is the same thing.

Comment: Now I (hopefully) understand this, what might be a good addition to this answer is the following:

$\omega^{<\omega}$ is a set-theoretical term for the eventually zero sequences of integers. So if you make a sum of $\omega^n\cdot s_n$ with increasing exponents $n$ using consecutive terms of any such sequence $S_n\in\omega^{<\omega}$ as coefficients, that's a bijection from $\omega^{<\omega}\to\omega^\omega$

Answer (score 4):

$X$ is the ordinal $\omega^\omega$. There is no going around that. The sequence $\omega^1, \omega^2, \omega^3, \ldots$ are all contained in $X$, so $X\geq \omega^\omega$ by definition of $\omega^\omega$. But $\omega^\omega\geq X$ because $\omega^\omega\notin X$. So they are equal.

I don't even know exactly what $\omega^{<\omega}$ means. It's certainly not an ordinal with conventional ordinal exponentiation. In set (and cardinal exponentiation), it would mean (the cardinality of) the set of all finite ordered tuples of natural numbers.

Comment: Thank-you.  I may be misunderstanding you.  Would this be fair... $X$ is the ordinal $\omega^\omega$ **if it's assumed to be an ordinal**.  But as a set $X\subsetneq\omega^\omega$ because it doesn't contain the infinitely long strings?

Comment: @samerivertwice Assuming $X$ to be an ordinal doesn't have anything to do with anything (it is an ordinal, and that's that). It is the _exponentiation_ which is either ordinal or not. That being said, yes, if the exponentiation is interpreted in the conventional set-exponential way, and you identify finite tuples with infinite, eventually constant sequences, then yes, $X\subset \omega^\omega$

Comment: Thanks. I need to get to better grips with the difference between ordinal and cardinal exponentiation.

Comment: Thank-you for this and apologies for the confusion. It turns out I was misunderstanding $\omega^{\omega}$ when I thought I was misunderstanding $\omega^{<\omega}$

Comment: FWFW $\omega^{<\omega}$ is a set-theoretical term for the eventually zero sequences of integers. So if you make a sum of $\omega$ with increasing exponents using consecutive terms of any such sequence as coefficients, that's a bijection from $\omega^{<\omega}\to\omega^\omega$